# Django many-to-many on existing form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

i have 2 tables, `WorkingHours` and `Employee`, in `Employee` i define 
`workingHours = models.ManyToManyField(WorkingHours)`. 
My `Employee` and `WorkingHours` have a foreign key to `User`.

Now i have some form for adding a WorkingHour (under some user) and i want to add on existing form that user can multiple choose between his `Employees`.

So i have existing form, that user can add `WorkingHours`, now i want to add a option that he can choose between his `Employees`. 
Now is realised only adding WorkingHours for some User, i want add a option to choose between his Employees, and i don't have any ideas how to do this.

So, for better understanding, i have user, who have `WorkingHours` and i want to add that user can choose which `Employee` "works" on this `WorkingHours`. If all fields be unchecked, i want to apply to all `Employees` that `WorkingHour`

I hope its not too complicated, if it is i will try to explain more in comments.

I am working on existing project, so i don't want to change a lot of code.

Thanx

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a specific question here. Maybe you can explain exactly what the problem/query is?

Comment: I edited the post, can you read again, please? :) I hope you see the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the basic problem. You need a Multiple choice field which is populated with the employees associated with that user.

Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) for some details/examples.

Basically you want something like this, this example doesn't do everything but I hope it's a start.

```
class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    employees = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required = False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)

def __init__(self, *args, **kw)
    user = kw.pop('user') # you need to pass user to into this function as a kw argument
    super(SimpleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    # this asssumes the user as a field (or related field reference) to employees
    # either way somehow you need to execute a query which gets the users employees.
    self.fields['employees'].choices = user.employees.all()

def save(self, *args):
    # if employees is empty set them all to selected
```

Comment: I will try, and let you know :)